# Output getting a zero for division

Tags: division

As I am trying to calculate 'PUT',  when I run the query I get 0 for that field.  Any suggestions on how to fix this?

```
SELECT 
   COUNT(x_reasons) as Cancel, 
   week, 
   COUNT(case when on_plan = '1' then 1 else null end) *1.0 / count(*) AS PUT
FROM inbound.otpu_plan_raw 
WHERE 
   week IN ('43','44','45','46','47','48', '49','50') 
   AND x_reasons like '%CLOSED%' and code = 'VC' 
Group By 1,2
```

Can someone tell me why I am getting a zero in Put output?

Comment: We do not see any output from this query, and we do not know which data is on the input side. So, how could we give a nice answer on something we cannot see ?   BTW: What RDBMS are you using? (MySQL, PostgreSQL, MSSQL, .... ?)

Comment: BTW:  Your query is invalid... (Because of the GROUP BY 4,1,2, and you only have 3 fields in your SELECT).

Comment: I updated the group by..  sorry output is the wrong language.  In the PUT column I am getting zeros

Comment: Take a look at the output of: `SELECT count(null)*1.0/42`

Comment: I cannot see how the output which contains 2 counts, an a weekNr, can be in a different language.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand.. Let me try the output

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.